# Disable "draw a shape to create a screen snip" screen overlay triggering from shortcut (Snip & Sketch?)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm not sure what is causing this. I have followed ***all*** of the instructions I've found online to disable both the Snipping Tool ***and*** Snip & Sketch (it is uninstalled from my system). Yet when I press Win+F20, I still see the screen go dim, and am prompted to draw a shape to create a screen snip.

How can I disable the shortcut functionality and prevent this behavior from occurring?

I really wish Windows OS was as user friendly with shortcut management as macOS. All of these hidden settings and shortcuts I can't figure out how to disable that use the Windows key are totally ruining my productivity.

Comment: Does this happen when [booting in Safe mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/)?

Comment: I don't know, and don't have time to check right now due to a big deadline. But assuming it doesn't, I couldn't exactly work in safe mode normally anyway.